# Detecting if you hit the bottom of window inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, shopify

I am working on an app for Shopify. I am using a lazy loading method; once the user scrolls to the bottom it loads more data. This seems to not work on all browsers. Particularly when the app is in the Shopify app window in an iframe. I know that the window.scroll is working, the if statement seems to be the problem

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height())  ){
            //*Load More data function
        }
}
```

The other problem is that Shopify prevents you from accessing the iframe so doing something like window.self !== window.top throws an exception